# VS2010 : Unable to start debugging Cannot locate Microsoft Internet Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight

i have created a simple silverligth project and when i tried to start debugging i had this errror :

"Unable to start debugging.

Cannot locate Microsoft Internet Explorer."

i have searched on the internet and i have found two solutions:

The first one :

"Navigating to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths I found that theiexplore.exe key was missing. So here's what I did:

Added the iexplore.exe key to the  registry.
Changed the (Default) REG_SZ value to C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe 
Added a new REG_SZ value called Path and set it to C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer
Restarted my Visual Studio.
"

This doesn't work, the iexplore.exe key is here.

(default) REG_SZ C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE

Path C:\Program Files( x86)\Internet Explorer;

the second is to right click into the aspx file and select "Browse With ..", and set internet explorer as default.

Is already that ...

I have launched older project in silverlight, and i have the same problem ...

i think  i got this bug because i have installed IE9 ...

anyone can help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer:

Navigating to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` I found that the `iexplore.exe` key was missing.

So here's what I did:

1. Added the `iexplore.exe` key to the registry.
2. Changed the (Default) REG_SZ value to `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe`
3. Added a new REG_SZ value called `Path` and set it to `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer`
4. Restarted my Visual Studio.